# Which publicly available services/apps use Twilio video?

Tags: video, twilio

As developing app using Twilio video, it would be useful to see examples of apps using it. There are few services listed on their website: https://customers.twilio.com/?q=products_used&c=AAAADA%3D%3D
but none of these seem to be easily accessible by public.
Do you have any apps where it would be possible to test the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Twilio Programmable Video 5 minute Set-up? This will allow you to test out the solution across multiple device types (iOS, Android, and JavaScript).

[Deploy your own video collaboration app in under 5 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSASQcHrmPg&t=15s)

[Deploy your own video collaboration app in five minutes or less (Blog Post)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/open-source-video-apps-reactjs-ios-android)